# how to test cell phone connectivity?

Tags: android

How to test network connection to tell if its a good signal or no signal? I would like to test this and do something if the connectivity isn't good. 
I also would like to test for wifi connectivity.

Comment: What qualifies as "good"? If I have a 4G connection with only 1 bar, I'm still getting 10 Mb/s. Additionally, Wifi can be connected to a router but have no internet connection (if the WAN cable on the router is unplugged, for example). It's probably better to try to use the data connection, and then handle the error if you're unable to connect to a remote host.

Comment: well how could I go about using the data connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question regarding whether it's a good connection or not, but this does figure out if it has a connection at all.  Perhaps you can look at the objects in this method and see if it tells you more.

```
private boolean hasNetworkConnection() {
    boolean HaveConnectedWifi = false;
    boolean HaveConnectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo)
    {
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                HaveConnectedWifi = true;
        if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                HaveConnectedMobile = true;
    }
    return HaveConnectedWifi || HaveConnectedMobile;
}
```

Comment: That's what I meant by the question. To test whether it has connectivity at all.